# How to prevent selectedItemBuilder from moving text up

Tags: flutter, user-interface, drop-down-menu

Using a `DropdownButton`, I need the selected item to be a different color than the list of items in the dropdown menu that appears when you tap the button. According to [the Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/style.html), I should use [`selectedItemBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html). As can be seen right there in [the example within the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html#material.DropdownButton.selectedItemBuilder.1), using the `selectedItemBuilder` results with the selected text being shifted up which does not look good.

[image: selected item in dropdown shifted up]

How can I get the selected item to be down in line with the drop-down icon where it is supposed to be while having separate colors for the menu items and the selected item?

Answer (score 8):

I found that this is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80411). A work around is to wrap the widget returned by the builder (and also the `hint` if you have one) in a `Center` widget.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  selectedItemBuilder: (_) {
    return items.map<Widget>((String item) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(item),
      );
    }).toList();
  },
  hint: Center(child: myHintWidget),

  ...
```